# How to access Telerik's RadDataGrid cell content from code behind for UWP?

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, telerik, grid

We have used DataGridTemplateColumn for our grid to display texbox under each column. We've a requirement to make the textboxes readonly if it contains any data (for data loading case). In order to achieve that, we need to access all text box controls under the radgrid. We've tried following approaches so far

- Find all child controls using VisualTreeHelper - No textbox control was found
- Tried with DataBindingComplete event

Is there any way to access the underlying cell's control from codebehind for RadDataGrid?

Alternative approach : Can we somehow user IsReadOnly property with some binding to check it's value and make the control readonly when value is there?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we somehow user IsReadOnly property with some binding to check it's value and make the control readonly when value is there?

Yes. You could certainly achieve this by using Binding. You just need to define a bool property and bind the IsReadOnly property of TextBox to this property. Then, you could change this bool value according to the text of TextBox.

Please refer to my following code sample for reference:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country">
                <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Country}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Flag">
                <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Flag}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Data> list = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        list.Add(new Data { Country = "Argentina",Flag="A"});
        list.Add(new Data {Country=string.Empty,Flag="B"});
        list.Add(new Data { Country = "China",Flag="C"});
        this.grid.ItemsSource = list;
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        list[1].Country = "Brazil";
    }
}

public class Data:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Country;
    public string Country
    {
        get { return _Country; }
        set
        {
            _Country = value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                IsReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsReadOnly = false;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("Country");
        }
    }

    private string _Flag;
    public string Flag
    {
        get { return _Flag;}
        set
        {
            _Flag = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Flag");
        }
    }

    private bool _IsReadOnly=false;
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _IsReadOnly; }
        set
        {
            _IsReadOnly = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsReadOnly");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your solution didn't work for my case. Here is the screenshot which I got after running your code snippet:
[link](https://ibb.co/jtPnfG)

Even though the textbox for first and last row contains text (for first few seconds), the texboxes are editable. What I want is to make these two textbosex readonly. Other textboxes will reamin editable.

p.s. I'm using dynamic binding from json. I don't have any specific model used for binding. So I think it would be best if I can access the controls any how.

p.s.1 : Thanks for the code snippet though :)

Comment: @user1814131 I just give you a simple code sample to show you how to set IsReadOnly dynamically by binding. If you want to make these two textboxes readonly when they contain text. You just only need to change the code logic in the `if/else` block in `Country` property.